# Why might an IP datagram be encapsulated in another IP datagram?

Tags: networking

I've seen references to this technique, but struggle to understand the purpose. What possible use might exist for such a construct?

Answer (score 1):

In order to create a network tunnel.

In order to remotely monitor traffic.

Answer (score 1):

Tunneling? Implement a private protocol? Certainly many, many other uses.

Answer (score -1):

It just took me a quick Google to come across an article explaining everything you need to know about the why and the how's of this:

http://penguin.dcs.bbk.ac.uk/academic/networks/network-layer/fragmentation/index.php

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The document refers to encapsulation of layers of protocol. Not an IP datagram within another IP datagram.